# Vote to delete tag

Tags: feature-request, support, tags, burninate-system

What does a member usually have to do when he sees a tag that clearly does not belong on SO?

Just now I've found a [dead](/questions/tagged/dead) tag, with only two questions. Another abused tag seems to be [code](/questions/tagged/code). They don't describe question from technical or any other side: seeing these tags doesn't help you to understand what's the question about.

Wouldn't it be useful to have some kind of 'remove tag' voting system, just like 'tag synonyms' we have now? Or is it supposed to be handled in other way?

PS I can't check all 187 questions for [code](/questions/tagged/code), so I'm not claiming there're no valid usages for it.

Comment: Coincidentally, I came to meta searching for a way to propose deletion of the "code" tag. Considering the context is StackOverflow, is there anything that *doesn't* pertain to code?

Comment: I opened a [request to delete the code tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83152/remove-code-tag), thanks to @Gnoupi's pointer to examples. It already has more upvotes than any SO question I've ever asked xD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You stated the main problem, a tag can have a correct use sometimes.

It would be something touching a lot of questions, and hard to undo in case of a mistake.

So I don't think there should be a kind of delete system from the community. A notification system could be useful, but there is meta and moderator flags, for that.

**Edit:** On meta, you can typically see examples under the ["retag-request" tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/retag-request).

Comment: My question was not to suggest some particular system (I don't care that much), but to find out what I should do in this situation. Do you know?

Comment: Or do you mean I should just post 'deletion request' on meta? Well, then please consider it a 'deletion request' :)

Comment: @Nikita - I reacted indeed for the "some kind of remove tag voting system", sorry. For "what to do", I suggest you post a retag request on Meta.