# delete 'dead' and 'code' tags

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request

As noted [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61888/vote-to-delete-tag), 'dead' and 'code' tags (2 and 181 questions respectively) don't describe question in any way, technical or not. Shouldn't we remove them?

Moved to a separate request, as suggested by **Gnoupi♦**.

Comment: We need a tag to act as an alternative to meta-tags like 'code'.  So we can proffer it as a synonym at the Info page.  'Untagged' doesn't work, I tried.  'Dead' is excellent.

Comment: Cancel that, doesn't work either.

Comment: +1 indeed worthless tag

Comment: Definitely add that tag to 98% of questions on this website - then migrate the other two to Programmers!

Comment: [Duplicate request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61895/delete-dead-and-code-tags)  Also, very occasionally there're [valid usages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291536/show-html-as-ode) of this tag (even if not particularly useful).

Comment: I really want to edit this question to include the 'code' tag that's being discussed. =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are imo definitely superfluous.

I retagged [one `[dead]` question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3542579/dead-code-error) to `[dead-code]` and deleted the tag from the [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554725/is-testswarm-com-dead-any-equivalents) since it indeed doesn't have any value.

The [`[code]` tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code) has however a few questions of which the tag actually needs to be merged with another tag, e.g. `[hash]+[code]` and `[code]+[completion]`. I have done it for a few questions.

Answer (score 8):

> Could there possibly be a more useless tag for a programming Q&A site?

I suggest [computer](/questions/tagged/computer).

Comment: I'd rather think the honor should go to `[programming]`

Comment: Or `[problem]`, but that was [already](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77059/tag-ban-request-problem-and-problems) nuked :)

Comment: That was a rhetorical question :P

Comment: There was a `[question]` tag at some point.

Comment: @Dan Now I find it surprising that there's no `[rhetorical]` tag.

Comment: And there's a `[bugs]` tag. Yeah, because all the other questions aren't about bugs, you know...

Comment: I'm going to go find something well suited for receiving slams from my head, preferably something that provides great audible feedback.. such as ... a wall.

Answer (score 3):

Actually the [codes](/questions/tagged/codes) tag is mostly worthless as well though far less popular (only 44 questions at the moment).  It has questions ranging from "teh sorce codes" to QR codes and error codes.  I'll go through and retag where appropriate but I wonder if it should be on the blacklist as well (there's certainly no appropriate tag synonym).

Answer (score 1):

OK, I removed [code](/questions/tagged/code) and [codes](/questions/tagged/codes) -- we'll see if they need to be blacklisted or not.