# Tag ban request: [problem] and [problems]

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, tag-block-request

The [problem](/questions/tagged/problem) and [problems](/questions/tagged/problems) tags are useless. Basically *every* question is about a problem already.

Comment: I have also my doubts about `[error]` by the way.

Comment: That tag would contain a lot of programming question, I guess you could look manually through it though...

Comment: @Tom: The problem is not the questions using those tags. On a proper SO it are *all* programming questions anyway.

Comment: Sorry for not being specific enough in that sentence, I meant [error].

Comment: @Tom: yes, I know (not that the same doesn't apply on `[problem]` and `[problems]`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jeff did this a while back, upvote me so I drop off the unanswered list